# pexpect : TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'"

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, pexpect

I am not much familiar with python. found this piece of code on "pexpect" example repo. I have made necessary changes. However, it is throwing "TypeError". Not able to figure out why.anybody can explain why and how can i fix this?

"pdb" was issuing error on "child = ssh_command(user, host, password)"

Error on pdb:

```
TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'"
```

Code is give below,

```
import pexpect

def ssh_command(user, host, password):
    new_sshkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' %(user, host))
    i = child.expect(new_sshkey, 'password: ')
    if i == 0:
        print 'ERROR.! SSH could not login.'
        print child.before, child.after
    if i == 1:
        child.sendline('yes')
        child.expect('password: ')
        i = child.expect('password: ')
        if i == 0:
            print 'ERROR.! Permission Denied'
            print child.before, child.after
    return child

def main():
    host = raw_input('Hostname: ')
    user = raw_input('Username: ')
    password = raw_input('Password: ')
    child = ssh_command(user, host, password)
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    print child.before

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the error is caused by this line

```
i = child.expect(new_sshkey, 'password: ')
```

According to the documentation the `expect` method is declared as follows

```
child.expect(pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False)
```

In your case you are passing `'password: '` as the second argument (`timeout`) which
probably should be an `int`.